# How to retrieve a document from firebase Realtime database with an onclick in the recycler view and the post to it

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

Hi I am trying to create an android application in kotlin that allows users to create their own community and then other users can post in said communities, but I am finding it difficult to figure out how to get the reference to the posts within a community through clicking on a community in the recycler view. I havent made a posts collection yet as I am not sure what is the best way to structure the collections  How I am creating my communities in my app,

```
fun createNewCommunity(community: CommunityModel) {               

    info("Firebase DB Reference : ${app.database}")                   
    val uid = app.currentUser!!.uid                                            
    val key = app.database.child("communites").push().key
                                                                            
    if (key == null) {                                                       
      info("Firebase Error : Key Empty")                            
      return                                                                  
    }
    community.uid = key
    val communityValues = community.toMap()                                   
    val childUpdates = HashMap<String, Any>()                                   
    childUpdates["/communities/$key"] = communityValues                           
    childUpdates["/user-communities/$uid/$key"] = communityValues
    app.database.updateChildren(childUpdates)                                     
}
```

[How my communities are being stored](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhTBk.png)

[The collections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xE7c7.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need? Also, the firebase docs are very very good and detailed you should check them out.

```
db.collection("communites")
        .get()
        .addOnSuccessListener { documents ->
            for (document in documents) {
                Log.d(TAG, "${document.id} => ${document.data}")
            }
        }
        .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
            Log.w(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", exception)
        }
```